# "Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo" plus

Tags: android

Force close during activity setup due to null pointer exception.

### error log:

```
08-02 12:50:33.913: E/main(383): Birds clicked on - new activity starting....id
08-02 12:55:22.977: D/AndroidRuntime(383): Shutting down VM
08-02 12:55:22.977: W/dalvikvm(383): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-02 12:55:23.104: E/AndroidRuntime(383): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-02 12:55:23.104: E/AndroidRuntime(383): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.kissta.safari/com.kissta.safari.viewscreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-02 12:55:23.104: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
08-02 12:55:23.104: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-02 12:55:23.104: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-02 12:55:23.104: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-02 12:55:23.104: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-02 12:55:23.104: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-02 12:55:23.104: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-02 12:55:23.104: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-02 12:55:23.104: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-02 12:55:23.104: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-02 12:55:23.104: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-02 12:55:23.104: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-02 12:55:23.104: E/AndroidRuntime(383): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-02 12:55:23.104: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1647)
08-02 12:55:23.104: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at com.kissta.safari.viewscreen.<init>(viewscreen.java:125)
08-02 12:55:23.104: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-02 12:55:23.104: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
08-02 12:55:23.104: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
08-02 12:55:23.104: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
08-02 12:55:23.104: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  ... 11 more
```

### Based on log commands, my app seems to fail when opening either viewscreen or viewxml:

```
// ...abridged...import android.widget.ImageButton; 

public class main extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainxml);

// ... abridged
ImageButton ibone = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
ibone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent explicitIntent1 = new Intent(main.this,viewscreen.class);
                explicitIntent1.putExtra("id", 1);
                startActivity(explicitIntent1);
                Log.e("main", "Birds clicked on - new activity starting...." + "id");
            }
        });


....further abridged...
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/iconanimal"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    <activity
        android:name=".splash"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".main"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".viewscreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
</activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

### In the viewscreen activity:

```
package com.kissta.safari;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

public class viewscreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
    OnGestureListener {

// references to our image
private animals animalclass = new animals();

int TotalAnimals; // starting from 0 of course (so an 11=12 fruit)
int currentAnimal = 0;

boolean active = true;
long starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long timedelay = 50;

ArrayList<Integer> imagearray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> soundarray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// ArrayList<String> printarray = new ArrayList<String>();

private ViewSwitcher switcher;
private GestureDetector gesturedetector;
public boolean viewone = true;
public int menuoption;
Handler myHandler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e("viewscreen1", "xml loading"); // does not reach here
    setContentView(R.layout.viewxml);
```

The log msg above is never triggered, implying to me that viewxml.xml is never reached(???).

Here is viewxml.xml:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Note:  Can't add more than 2 views to a ViewSwitcher -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fullscreenrelative"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>

<ViewSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/viewSwitcher"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomtablerow"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:inAnimation="@anim/in_animation"
    android:outAnimation="@anim/out_animation" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/view1relative"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/swan"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/clear32" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/view2relative"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/kangaroo" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:src="@drawable/clear32" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ViewSwitcher>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/bottomtablerow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#303030"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:background="@drawable/whiteleft"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:src="@drawable/clear" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:src="@drawable/clear" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:background="@drawable/whiteright"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>

</RelativeLayout>`
```

PS I am now also getting an AVD error which may be unrelated:
"emulator: ERROR: Could not load OpenGLES emulation library: Could not load DLL!"
I don't believe I am using OpenGL at all though.
see common bug report at http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33336

PSS my app is also rejecting the use of non-google api VMs

PSS here is the full main file as requested:
    package com.kissta.safari;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class main extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainxml);
    // android:tileMode="repeat"

    Log.e("main", "main all good");

    SoundManager.getInstance();
    SoundManager.initSounds(main.this);
    SoundManager.loadSounds();
    Log.e("main", "sm LoadSounds worked, all done.");

        // SECTION FOR GAME CHOICE BUTTONS!!!!!!!!!
        // ***
        ImageButton ibone = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        ibone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent explicitIntent1 = new Intent(main.this,viewscreen.class);
                explicitIntent1.putExtra("id", 1);
                startActivity(explicitIntent1);
                Log.e("main", "Birds clicked on - new activity starting...." + "id"); // it gets this far perfectly fine
            }
        });

        // ***

        ImageButton ibtwo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        ibtwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Playsound2.stop();
                Intent explicitIntent2 = new Intent(main.this,
                        viewscreen.class);
                explicitIntent2.putExtra("id", 2);
                startActivity(explicitIntent2);
            }
        });

        // ***

        ImageButton ibthree = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
        ibthree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Playsound2.stop();
                Intent explicitIntent3 = new Intent(main.this,
                        viewscreen.class);
                explicitIntent3.putExtra("id", 3);
                startActivity(explicitIntent3);
            }
        });

        // ***

        ImageButton ibfour = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
        ibfour.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Playsound2.stop();
                Intent explicitIntent4 = new Intent(main.this,
                        viewscreen.class);
                explicitIntent4.putExtra("id", 4);
                startActivity(explicitIntent4);
            }
        });

        ImageButton ibfive = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
        ibfive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Playsound2.stop();
                Intent explicitIntent5 = new Intent(main.this,
                        viewscreen.class);
                explicitIntent5.putExtra("id", 5);
                startActivity(explicitIntent5);
            }
        });

        ImageButton ibsix = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton6); // settings - adjust
        ibsix.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Playsound2.stop();
                Intent explicitIntent6 = new Intent(main.this,
                        viewscreen.class);
                explicitIntent6.putExtra("id", 6);
                startActivity(explicitIntent6);
            }
        });

        ImageButton ibsev = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonau); // settings - adjust
        ibsev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Playsound2.stop();
                Intent explicitIntent6 = new Intent(main.this,
                        viewscreen.class);
                explicitIntent6.putExtra("id", 7);
                startActivity(explicitIntent6);
            }
        });




        // / *************** END OF GAME CHOICE BUTTONS


    }



}
```

Comment: Could you post your viewxml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent explicitIntent1 = new Intent(main.this,viewscreen.class);
explicitIntent1.putExtra("id", 1);
startActivity(explicitIntent1);
Log.e("main", "this finished ok"); // app gets to here fine
```

Afer this code, there is come which is something like

```
findViewById(..
```

Check if this ID exist in your xml

Comment: I have checked all the IDs I can, including the spelling as I know that can cause this error but I have not located a mistake.

Comment: I suspect this line is doing problem "// references to our image
private animals animalclass = new animals();"
What does this line do actually?

Comment: animal is another class I have that holds a list of images and sounds. I am using the line you specified to create an instance of animal called "animalclass". This is required to access animal latter in the viewscreen class. It was working prior to my error so perhaps it's unrelated.